# Geolocalization symbol

Tags: symbols

If you were very kind of suggest me how can I implement the geolocalization symbol inside a latex environment I would be greatly thankful of being granted of your ample knowledge and patience.

I'm looking for something like this
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Are you looking for a specific symbol? Perhaps you could add a picture of what you're looking for.

Comment: Maybe `\faMapMarker*` from [`fontawesome5`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome5) ?

Comment: Have a look at the brand new `mercatormaps` package.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat have you product-examples of this package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest one of the following symbols from `fontawesome5`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\begin{document}
\faMapMarked{}
\faMapMarked*{}
\faMapMarker{}
\faMapMarker*{}
\faMapPin{}
\end{document}
```

If you want neither of these options, you could always construct another symbol out of those of `fontawesome5`. Here are two examples (which are far from perfect, but that might give a start).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{bm}
\newlength{\markerwidth}
\settowidth{\markerwidth}{\faMapMarker}
\newcommand{\mapmarker}{%
    \faMapMarker\hspace*{-\markerwidth}%
    \raisebox{.6pt}{\makebox[\markerwidth][c]{%
        \scalebox{.88}{\color{white}\faMapMarker}%
    }}\hspace*{-\markerwidth}%
    \raisebox{3.3pt}{\makebox[\markerwidth][c]{%
        \scalebox{.7}{\(\bm{\circ}\)}%
    }}%
}
\newcommand{\othermapmarker}{%
    \faMapMarker\hspace*{-\markerwidth}%
    \raisebox{.6pt}{\makebox[\markerwidth][c]{%
        \scalebox{.88}{\color{white}\faMapMarker*}%
    }}\hspace*{-\markerwidth}%
    \raisebox{3.7pt}{\makebox[\markerwidth][c]{%
        \scalebox{.5}{\color{white}\textbullet}%
    }}%
}
\begin{document}
\faMapMarker*{}
\mapmarker{}
\othermapmarker{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: the fourth is fine but it is filled in black